# Params missing link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Here's the html link:

```
<%= link_to "Select Thumb", update_thumb_src_video_path(video), method: :patch, video: {thumb_src: name} %>
```

When the error pops, the params listed are the id, authenticity_token and method, but not the video params.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 <%= link_to "Select Thumb", update_thumb_src_video_path(video, video: {thumb_src: name}), method: :patch %>
```